# How to make OneToOne relationship optional for multiple inherited classes?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, entity, typeorm, ts-node

Suppose I have a class `Animal` which are inherited by `Dog` and `Cat`.

```
export class Animal extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id:number;
}

@Entity()
export class Cat extends Animal{
   ...
}

@Entity()
export class Dog extends Animal{
   ...
}
```

Now, I want to show a `OneToOne` relationship with their owner.

```
@Entity
export class Owner extends BaseEntity{
   ....
 
   @OneToOne()
   pet:???
}
```

`Owner` is a class which has an attribute `pet` that can either be a Cat or a Dog.
How can I achieve this using typeorm?

---

Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you do it

---

```
@Entity()
@TableInheritance({ column: { type: "varchar", name: "type" } })
export class Content {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
 
    @Column()
    title: string;
    
    @Column()
    description: string;
    
}
```

```
@ChildEntity()
export class Photo extends Content {
    
    @Column()
    size: string;
    
}
```

```
@ChildEntity()
export class Question extends Content {
    
    @Column()
    answersCount: number;
    
}
```

```
@ChildEntity()
export class Post extends Content {
    
    @Column()
    viewCount: number;
    
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what should be done in Owner.pet, should pass the Animal entity? will Animal or the Child be stored on database with its relationship with Owner?

Answer (score 2):

You can use @ChildEntity() for children and @Entity() for main class in typeorm.